# Application.html.erb template inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a situation in rails (version 4.04, ruby version 2.1) where I've been using the standard application.html.erb to define the main framework for my site, header, footer, nav bar, etc. When I got to an inner div, call it, inner-content, thats where I put a <% yield %> statement so that the sub template can take over and place its content in the correct place (for example products#show or products#index have show.html.erb and index.html.erb respectively which just the content for those actions).

The problem is I realized I was duplicated some code in those sub templates. In ever one of them (except one) I always was starting off like this:

```
<div class="columns large-6 medium-6 center-small">
  <div class="inner_wrapper">
```

And I was always ending like this:

```
</div>
</div>
```

So I was thinking, I shouldn't be repeating all this code. I should move this into application.html.erb so that every template automatically gets the inner-content set up correctly.

The problem is that one action I was talking about. There is one action that has a different setup. I don't want to have to type in those extra 2 divs for every sub-layout except one. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to check which controller your currently using this in your application.html.erb

```
<% if params[:controller] == "controller name" %>
    <div>
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
<% else %>
    <div class="different div"> 
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Not sure if this the best way, but its one way to do it.

Comment: Awesome idea. I had to reference the action too with the action_name helper but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Create a different layout file and call it maybe products_layout.html.erb.

Then in the controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    layout: 'products_layout'
    ....
end
```

Or do it on a per action

```
def show
  render 'show', layout: 'products_layout'
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html